# Combine text from multiple rows based on IDs but remove consecutive duplicate entry

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, group-by, collect

I have a dataframe

| id | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aa |
| 3 | uy |
| 1 | bb |
| 1 | cr |
| 1 | cr |
| 1 | cr |
| 1 | qe |
| 2 | yt |
| 2 | yt |
| 3 | uy |
| 4 | po |
| 1 | cr |

I was able to combine them like this using collect_Set method

```
df  = df.groupby("id").agg(f.concat_ws(", ", f.collect_list(df.col1)).alias('col1'))
```

| id | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aa,bb,cr,cr,cr,qe,cr |
| 2 | yt,yt |
| 3 | uy,uy |
| 4 | po |

But I want my final output to drop consecutive duplicate items , something like this

| id | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aa,bb,cr,qe,cr |
| 2 | yt |
| 3 | uy |
| 4 | po |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
w=Window.partitionBy('id')

df= (df.withColumn('index',  monotonically_increasing_id())#Create an index to orderBy
        .withColumn('index',lag('col1').over(w.orderBy('index'))).na.fill('')#Create a column to use in filter
       .where(col('col1')!=col('index')).drop('index')#filter
       .groupBy('id').agg(array_join(collect_list('col1'),',').alias('col1'))#groupby, collect_list and the array_join the outcome
     .show())

+---+--------------+
| id|          col1|
+---+--------------+
|  1|aa,bb,cr,qe,cr|
|  2|            yt|
|  3|            uy|
|  4|            po|
+---+--------------+
```

Comment: collect_Set will not give aa,bb,cr,qe,cr , instead it will give aa,bb,cr,qe for ID 1

Comment: Please see my edit, happy to help further

Comment: Please accept and upvote if ok,If it has issues, let me know